# Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) => if no debug or .to_yaml used

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I get an error with the following code, but with a logger row or debug is the output correct. It's a little bit strange for me. (Rails 3.1.0 and 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.7)

Controller contains:

```
def index
  @privatmessages = Privatmessage.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @privatmessages }
  end
end
```

index.htm.erb

```
<% @privatmessages.each do |privatmessage| %>
   <%= privatmessage.id %>
<% end %>
```

That code produce the error:

*ArgumentError in Privatmessages#index
Showing ../app/views/privatmessages/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)*

But the output is correct and without errors, if I add the following line at the controller:

```
logger.info "Messages: {#@privatmessages.to_yaml}"
```

or if I add inside of the each loop at the index.html.erb the line:

```
<%= debug privatmessage %>
```

Has anyone an advice for me?

Answer (score 2):

Issue found and solved!

The problem was that I used "send" as a column name in the table, but "send" is a reserved method for Rails core. After renaming the column in the table to "sendout" it works.

Comment: process was also a reserved word